# Is this Johnson behaviour unusual?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

I'm currently running a 1st edition adventure (using 5th edition time and rules). The fixer of the group said he got a potential Johnson waiting at his bar. The Johnson took a glance at the group and if they are interested they should meet at another night club that is a more secure location (less people and less eavesdropers around) and they should ask for a specific person there that will give more details. (Johnson is clearly corp and not used to dealing with runners.)

Players immediately called bullshit and thats a trap as that is NOT how Johnsons act at all. I'm a bit confused as I read THAT behaviour a few times in older adventures. The mage didn't even try to assense if the Johnson is trying to ambush them or telling the truth.

Thus the question: Is that really unusual or does it fall under normal Johnson behaviour in the "newer" times?

Comment: I've not been playing Shadowrun in a long time, but this lingo sounds really cool.

Answer (score 8):

### Things haven't changed that much from 1E.

I mean, I don't want to go all "NeoNET crawl, first result" here, but:

> **1. Private room in a nightclub.** Provides the seclusion you want, doesn't have a strong dress code, and has a crowd nearby to keep the participants honest.
>
> -- "Why to Meet Where", Shadowrun 5th ed p. 28

That list goes on to run the gamut from "abandoned warehouse by the docks" to "posh upscale restaurant", so there's not, like, "a usual place that Mr. Johnson meets you". There's really no "usual thing Mr. Johnson does" because there is no one Mr. Johnson. There's a whole variety of people with their own motivations and preferences.

On its own, "a private room in a nightclub" is not a suspicious place for Mr. Johnson to ask for a meet.

#### But let's talk about Mr. Johnson.

Mr. Johnson is an anonymous figure who wants to pay you money to do crimes. **Everything about that is suspicious.** That's why the same page of the rulebook has sentiments like "The number of ways Mr. Johnson can screw you could fill a book bigger than this one."

Mr. Johnson's opposite number is **your fixer**, who is interested in being a reputable middleman and has a vested interest in both capable runners and Johnsons who don't screw them over. In a case like this where the Johnson is a newcomer to the scene, the fixer should basically have the advantage and be able to vet the setup to a reasonable degree of confidence.

There's also **legwork**, the part of the game for (among other things) following up on PC suspicions. Investigate the site of the meet, the Johnson's purported interest, the intended job. Use the skills you have to obtain information, that most precious and useful of treasures.

It's not wrong to be suspicious of anything about Mr. Johnson. But from a "not starving in the streets" perspective, there's got to be some threshold at which you take the money anyway.

#### And you should talk to your players.

So, you haven't really said how much your players were talking in character to the Johnson as runners and how much they were talking out of character to you the GM.

If your players were talking purely in character to the Johnson, at its most charitable this is an attempt to get some leverage over the Johnson by feigning hesitance after he's already expressed interest.

If your players were talking purely out of character to you, at its least charitable they're telling you that they can't trust you and aren't willing to participate in even the most straightforward thing you can offer up.

The truth is probably somewhere in the middle. Maybe your players have suspicions of Mr. Johnson but aren't sure what to do with them, exactly.

So, you need to establish what kind of game you're going to run. Usually this is a job for something often called "session zero", a little pre-play expectations setting. Like, if it's true: "The shadows of Seattle are a hive of scum and villainy, and deciding who to trust is always an open question. But I'm not going to lay any dialogue traps that'll TPK you if you don't say the right thing or ask the right question. Being suspicious and taking precautions is part of your job description, and I'll always let you use the skills and tools you have to do that."

And then you need to run according to that. In the now, be open with your PCs about what they know - "your fixer gives you a subtle look and nod as the Johnson babbles about how to identify yourself to the club hostess. He's already cleared the secondary meet site." - and what they can do to find out more.

Answer (score 6):

## The Shadows never change

From Shadowrun 1 to <strike>6</strike> 5 Js has been there. Many many different Js. But they never stopped from being persistent assholes of which about one in 6 was out to get the ass of the runners screwed over to skip paying while the other 5 were just after some deniable assets. And every J is different but the same: they are a J, their *role* in a run is to get you your info on what to do while it is the Fixer's job to get you the info that it is going on in the first place. Just like the Guard's role usually is to be a complication of sorts, without the J, there is no run. But What makes a good or bad J?

### J didn't behave *that* unusual

From my experience of about a decade of Shadowrun, 2nd though 5th edition, The Johnson was far out of the most problematic J I was faced with by various GMs. Inspection at one place and then talking in a back room? That's nothing. Sure, it might seem *complicated* but it might also be to cover the butt of the J. I have had to run through loops like these to get to the meeting with the J. Some of the most memorable ones:

- J never showed their face, but instead sat in the neighboring room with bulletproof glass in between and only lit from the back, talking through a speaker. Turned out that who we saw was just a puppet and J was miles away using the Matrix - but the job went without a hitch.
- J invited us into *their* office in a corporate building under construction and spoke pretty openly about hiring us to assault said corporation's competitor. Can'T be that easy? J was actually the subcontractor that renovated the building and sicked us on the actual owner of the building because there were outstanding bills.
- To get to J, we had to follow leads through 3 bars to finally get there, and get a couple hundred per head for showing up. Allegedly, J weeded who he'd have there that way, and the following investigation went... mostly as we planned.
- J asked us to meet at the container yard and gestured *into* a container containing some sort of office where the meeting would be held. We were nervous that we'd be press-ganged by closing the door on us and shipping us to the place where J wanted - and demanded the door open at all times. We ended up getting shipped out for a mission in a *different* container, but we had agreed to the lucrative terms.
- J asked us to arrive in our best 'Sunday suits', then did arrive in a stretch limo to the meeting spot at the edge of a low society area. They asked us to get in. We got the briefing on the car ride to the very spot that J wanted us to mess up a party of a competing Exec. Dang, we left behind about a half to dozen pocket pistols in that car!
- J met us in the back of a seedy bar downtown. He said "It'll be an easy job" - and was promptly gunned down by two of the present runners. Simultanously. It's **never** an easy job.

### What went wrong?

Well, ok, back to your problem at hand: What triggered off the Runners? The situation had ample opportunity to make them queasy. Relocating the meeting isn't the most professional, but not the most unprofessional either. J might have wanted  secure backroom in the first place but screen in a more public area - or do the interview in the car there.

The runners might have suspected that they were denied their chance for the job. Or that it was a setup. Which indeed could have been true, or not.

It might not have been the J they met there, but J's assistant, who was roped into it to take the fall in case the runners were caught. Or to buy J a couple of moments to actually know who he was about to hire. There's so many possible good reasons that it is speculation unless you talk to the GM.

But were the runners right to deny the job? Yes, and that's their right. However, the players made two crucial errors:

1. There is no such single way "*that is NOT how Johnsons act at all*" or vice versa. As I pointed out, J's have been behaving much shadier to me and got away with it. Or much less conspicuous and chose one wrong sentence for which they got gunned down.
2. It's the GM's Shadowrun - and he can demand an etiquette or other rolls to inform the players with more information so the **characters** can interpret the situation. Maybe in his *Shadow City* that setup is normal?!

### How to save the situation

Ok, there are two things that need to be done: Talk about your goals and adventure styles you like, both as a GM and Player. Like, do you like to hunt red herrings or do you love to be thrown into the action? In short, have some kind of Session 0. Or Session #.5, where # is your current session number. On the other hand, you should allow both GM and players to explain their view of this one situation, as the players might have misunderstood or misinterpreted queues that the GM didn't want to give - and possibly salvage it.

#### Put it on the bench

If I was the GM, and the players refused that one setup for the run, I'd take out a reserve job, have the Fixer be a little angry that they didn't even show up to the actual meeting (because they forgot to mention that), but then roll with it - and reuse the run some other time, using a slightly altered hook. Maybe *just* send them to the other bar in this 6-floor nightclub called Dante's Inferno to get to the *right* backroom, not send them through half the town first.

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about Shadowrun 6E - is it struck out because, like Highlander, 5E had no sequels, or struck out because 6E has demoted it from headline play to one among many possibilities, like hooding on your own initiative?

Comment: It's a case of highlander.